# Help create TableLayout inside .java activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tablelayout

I am having problem create a tablelayout inside an activity.  So far i managed to display the resulting query using textview.

```
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id) ).setText( listItem.getId()+""); 
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name) ).setText( listItem.getName() ); 
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_age) ).setText( listItem.getAge()+"" );
```

i would appreciate it if you can help me turn this textview into tablelayout.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the layout xml.  If this is the only output of the activity the xml would look something like:

```
<Table_Layout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretch_columns="*">

<TableRow>
<TextView
android:id="@+/tv_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+/tv_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+/tv_age"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</TableRow>

</Table_Layout>
```

If there will be more rows wrap it all in a ScrollView so the ui is scrollable.